# Getting filesystem path of class always returning ./

Tags: java

When in Eclipse, if I run

```
Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
```

it returns the correct path. But when I run it outside of Eclipse, it always returns "./" as the directory, and I don't know why. I've also tried getPath(), and that did the same thing.

Edit: Turns out "./" is the current directory. Does anyone know of a way to get the ABSOLUTE directory of the currently running file?

Comment: You're getting a relative path. What happens if you ask for an absolute path with `File.getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: Lemme check quickly.

Comment: Null pointer exception on doing new File(path) where path is "./"

Comment: Never mind, the path is null for some reason.

Comment: Undid an edit I had done, now it returns C:/Users/username/.

Comment: Is that the location of your jar file?

Comment: Never mind, I found the method:

Comment: System.getProperty("java.class.path");

Comment: I'm glad you've found something that works for you. Usually that's the not the best way to find the location of a particular jar file, because the classpath can contain multiple paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the path of a file inside your project on eclipse you could always **right click** on the file and **click on properties**, and check the path!

but also, you could use `System.getProperty("java.class.path");`

here is the doc to guide you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Also, I was trying to find the path of the file so I could make an auto-updater, not for finding it inside Eclipse :P